# Proof by contradiction with only one example

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, inequality, logic

given following inequations:

1. $A > 2$
2. $0.5 \leq \log A$

If I know that A is greater than 2, for example let's say 3. I can assume that the second equation does not hold for 3, and say that this is a contradiction?

I don't know, if showing just one example is enough to show a contradiction.

Comment: No, there is no contradiction.  There are lots of values of $A$ that satisfy both of these inequalities.

Comment: These are inequalities, not equations.

Comment: Depends on what you need to prove. If you need to find all the values that satisfy these inequalities, then it is not enough. If you need to prove or disprove that for all $A$ both inequalities hold, then it is enough.

Comment: I have to show that for every A the second inequation holds, if I give one example that it doesn't hold, can I say it's a contradiction?

Comment: $e^{0.5} < 2. $

Answer (score 1):

As other said, these are inequalities, in which you can obtain where A belongs to.
$A>2$ you obtain, $A\in]2,+\infty[$.
On the other hand, $0.5\leq logA$, I suppose it's neperian logarithm, so:
$$e^{0.5}\leq A$$
So you can find easily where $A$ belongs to.

Hope this can help.